# How to filter google calendar REST API events by attendee's email

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm accessing  [Google Calendar REST API for Calendar Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), trying to figure out a proper notation for **q** parameter, to filter all events where one of the attendees is identified by email (let's say foo@bar.com)

I've tried: q=attendee.email:foo@bar.com, q=attendee.email=foo@bar.com, q=attendees.email=foo@bar.com, q=attendees.email="foo@bar.com"...

but with no results (empty list, once the **q** parameter is filled in)

Is it supported at all?

Is there a list of valid **q** parameter fields to filter by?

Answer (score 1):

The "q" parameter is working like a text search in event list.

> Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in the
> following fields: summary, description, location, attendee's
> displayName, attendee's email. Optional.

It possible to search events with specified email:

> ```
>      calendar.events.list(
>       {
>         q: 'attendee@email.test',
>         calendarId: 'primary',
>         timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
>         maxResults: 10,
>         singleEvents: true,
>         orderBy: 'startTime',
>       }
> ```

It should return events where 'attendee@email.test' is specified

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any Calendar API call to directly search for attendees.

However, you can achieve this by code. You have to list all the events, loop through them and filter the events if the email you wrote coincides with the email in the attendees. For example:

```
function searchEvents() {

  var calendarId = "primary";
  var email = "test@email.com";
  var result = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId).items;

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){ 

    if (result[i].attendees != undefined){ //Filters out the events without attendees

      for (var j = 0; j < result[i].attendees.length; j++){

        if (result[i].attendees[j].email == email){
          Logger.log(result[i]); //It returns all the event information
        }       

      }

    }
  }

}
```

The full resource object returned:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "timeZone": string,
  "summaryOverride": string,
  "colorId": string,
  "backgroundColor": string,
  "foregroundColor": string,
  "hidden": boolean,
  "selected": boolean,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "notificationSettings": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "type": string,
        "method": string
      }
    ]
  },
  "primary": boolean,
  "deleted": boolean,
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      string
    ]
  }
}
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [Events List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)
- [List Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource)